# why Entry point address is 0x800107d,but first instruction start 0x800107c

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, gnu, cortex-m

using arm-none-eabi-readelf -h ideself.elf
could find:

```c
Entry point address:               0x800107d
```

using  arm-none-eabi-objdump -D ideself.elf
could find:

```
0800107c <Reset_Handler>:                       
 800107c:   f8df d034   ldr.w   sp, [pc, #52]   ; 80010b4 <LoopForever+0x2>
 8001080:......................................................
```

why the start reset_handler is not equal 0x800107d instead of 0x800107c

the byte in the 0x800107c don't execute? execute 3/4 four bytes instructions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ARM processors have two different instruction sets, Thumb and ARM. The Thumb instruction set has 16 bits per instruction, and the ARM instruction set has 32 bits per instruction. Instructions are aligned in memory.

The value of the instruction pointer is therefore even, meaning that bit 0 of the instruction's address is 0. This makes the bit "free to use" for other purposes.

So, the processor decides on bit 0 of the target address whether they continue in Thumb mode or in ARM mode. A bit 0 = 1 switches the processor into Thumb mode, resulting in an odd target address. However, the actual instruction's address is still even and by one less.

Answer (score 2):

The least significant bit of a jump/branch address indicates whether the target is to be executed in Thumb/Thumb2 or ARM instruction set mode.  The LSB is not used as part of the address.

However on Cortex-M the *only* instruction set supported is Thumb2, any attempt to enter ARM mode will cause an INVSTATE UsageFault exception.
On cores that support both instruction sets, such as Cortex-A, the bit is used to switch the mode for "[interworking](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0471/m/interworking-arm-and-thumb)" - code using a mix of instruction set modes.

Thumb instruction set is a 16-bit instruction set for greater code density used of some older ARM architectures such as ARM7TDMI, whilst ARM is a purely 32 bit instruction set.  Thumb2 is a hybrid 16/32 bit instruction set.